# DataGridView moves rows to bottom when cell is updated with Unbound data

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is styled with code and is using data from a SQLite Database
The Database is NOT bound to the DataGridView. A number of events are triggered when I click on a row.
First the Database is updated with today's date.
And the cell that contain's that date reflects the change.
I then call a sort on the column based on the cells value. With this code

```
 dgvLinks.Sort(dgvLinks.Columns(3), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

The process works as expected with no issues IF I omit these lines of code from the Sub Routine ViewSearches() that populates the DataGridView.

```
  If rowCount <= 25 Then
     maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
     For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
        dgvLinks.Rows.Add(" ")
     Next
  End If
```

I can use these empty rows if I make a call to repopulate the DataGridView with ViewSearches()
I am trying to avoid this design as it seems like a over use of resource.
The ERROR that is happening is the 4 rows that contain data are moved to the bottom of the DataGridView and above these 4 rows with data are the empty rows. I will post the relevant code below.
**My question How can I keep the empty rows and populate DataGridView so the rows with data are at the top of the DataGridView?**

Here is a Screen Shot after I selected LID 2. It is updated and bubbled to the bottom of the DGV.
[image: DataGridView]

```
    Private Sub ViewSearches()

    Dim intID As Integer
    Dim strChannelName As String
    Dim strLinkAddress As String
    Dim strLastVisit As String
    Dim strLinkType As String
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim maxRowCount As Integer
    'Dim emptyStr As String = "  "

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
        conn.Open()

        Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand("", conn)

            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable"
            ' Line of CODE Above works with If statement in  While rdr
            '==========================================================
            'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = 'News'"

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LinkTable WHERE ytSiteType = @site"
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@site", DbType.String).Value = gvSLT

            Using rdr As SQLite.SQLiteDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                'dgvLinks.DataSource = rdr
                'Statement Above use when DB is bound to dgvLinks
                '=================================================

                While rdr.Read()
                    intID = CInt((rdr("LID")))
                    strChannelName = rdr("ytChannelName").ToString
                    strLinkAddress = rdr("ytLinkAddress").ToString
                    strLastVisit = rdr("ytLastVisit").ToString
                    strLinkType = rdr("ytSiteType").ToString
                    'If strLinkType = gvSLT Then
                    dgvLinks.Rows.Add(intID, strChannelName, strLinkAddress, strLastVisit)
                    rowCount = rowCount + 1
                    'End If
                End While

                dgvLinks.Sort(dgvLinks.Columns(3), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

            End Using

            If rowCount <= 25 Then
                maxRowCount = 25 - rowCount
                For iA = 1 To maxRowCount
                    dgvLinks.Rows.Add(" ")
                Next
            End If

        End Using
    End Using
    'FindEmpty()
End Sub
```

Click Event with Update to Database

```
    Private Sub dgvLinks_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvLinks.CellClick

    selRow = e.RowIndex

    If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
        gvalertType = "4"
        frmAlert.ShowDialog()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Dim col As DataGridViewColumn = Me.dgvLinks.Columns(e.ColumnIndex)
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Me.dgvLinks.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If row.Cells(2).Value Is Nothing Then
        gvalertType = "5"
        frmAlert.ShowDialog()
        Return
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf gvTxType = "View" Then
        webPAGE = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
        siteID = CInt(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString())

        UpdateSiteData()

        ''MsgBox("Stop " & selRow)
        'dgvLinks.ClearSelection()
        'dgvLinks.Refresh()
        'dgvLinks.RefreshEdit()

        Process.Start(webPAGE)

        'dgvLinks.Columns.Clear()

        ''dgvLinks.Rows.Clear()
        ''ViewSearches()


    ElseIf gvTxType = "Delete" Or gvTxType = "Update" Then
        gvID = CInt(row.Cells(0).Value)
        gvSiteName = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString
        gvSiteURL = row.Cells(2).Value.ToString
        frmADE.Show()
        Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

Update Routine

```
    Public Sub UpdateSiteData()

    Dim dateToday = Date.Today
    dateToday = CDate(CDate(Date.Today).ToString("M-d-yyyy"))

    Using conn As New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;"),
        cmd As New SQLiteCommand("UPDATE LinkTable SET ytLastVisit = @ytLastVisit WHERE LID =" & siteID, conn)
        conn.Open()

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ytLastVisit", DbType.String).Value = dateToday.ToString("M-d-yyyy")

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        dgvLinks.Rows(selRow).Cells(3).Value = dateToday.ToString("M-d-yyyy")

        'Line of code above INSERTS value in Last Visit Column at the correct ROW
        'NOT needed if you reload data from the database
        '=========================================================================
        'dgvLinks.Refresh()
        'dgvLinks.RefreshEdit()

        dgvLinks.Sort(dgvLinks.Columns(3), ListSortDirection.Ascending)

    End Using

End Sub
```

You will see a number of things I have tried commented out.
As I said I can FIX the issue if I make a call to the ViewSearches() Sub Routine.

```
    Private Sub StyleDGV()

    'Sets Design of the DataGridView
    '===============================
    dgvLinks.DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Times New Roman", 13.0F, FontStyle.Bold)
    dgvLinks.ColumnCount = 4
    dgvLinks.Columns(0).Width = 60   'ID
    dgvLinks.Columns(1).Width = 325  'Site Name 325
    dgvLinks.Columns(2).Width = 860  'Site Url 860
    dgvLinks.Columns(3).Width = 154  'LastVisit 140
    'Option with no blank rows increase col count to 5
    'OR increase width of col(3) WHY? because the scroll bar is not showing 
    ' TOTAL Width 1450 Height 488
    '=============================
    'To Set Col Header Size Mode = Enabled
    'To Set Col Header Default Cell Styles DO in Properties
    'dgvLinks.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"

    dgvLinks.ColumnHeadersHeight = 10 'Sans Serif 'Tahoma
    dgvLinks.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font("Sans Serif", 12.0F, FontStyle.Bold)

    dgvLinks.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue
    dgvLinks.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow

    'DGV Header Names
    dgvLinks.Columns(0).Name = "LID"
    dgvLinks.Columns(1).Name = "Site Name"
    dgvLinks.Columns(2).Name = "Site URL"
    dgvLinks.Columns(3).Name = "Last Visit"

    dgvLinks.Columns(0).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvLinks.Columns(1).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvLinks.Columns(2).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    dgvLinks.Columns(3).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable

End Sub
```

**Any one following this question the FIX that permitted keeping the empty rows was to just omit the sort command in the Update to Database Sub Routine**

Comment: It is difficult to tell exactly “why” the empty rows get set above existing rows, I can only guess a sort may do be doing this. However, I have to ask… “why” do you choose to NOT use a data source to the grid? It “appears” you have a data source available but you are not using it… why? Manually creating the rows is just more work for you and a data source usually will simplify things a lot. Is there a specific reason why you don’t use a data source to the grid? And “why” are you adding “empty” rows to the grid?

Comment: @JohnG I have never had good results using bound data to the DataGridView. As for the empty rows I use them because I do not like the look of the empty space below the rows that have data. I guess I could shrink the DGV and as the rows with data expand increase the Height of the DGV But the scroll bars make it easy to just add a few blank row's As for the empty rows above the existing rows this only happens if I do the sorting I am guessing this happens because of some setting in the DGV Thanks for the comment

Comment: @JohnG Here is an novel updae If I use these two lines of code in the Update routine it works just the wrong sort direction but the rows with data stay at the top of the DGV             dgvLinks.Sort(dgvLinks.Columns(3), ListSortDirection.Descending)
            dgvLinks.Refresh()

Comment: From your last comment, it appears clear my assumption was correct in reference to the “sort” causing the empty rows to appear before the rows with data. It would seem to me that your desire to add empty rows because … _”I do not like the look of the empty space below the rows that have data”_ … comes with some consequences. I would say to simply not add the empty rows until you have sorted the data, however, if the empty rows already exist and you need to re-sort the data, then you have extra work to “remove” the empty rows, sort the rows with data, then add the empty rows back.

Comment: _”I guess I could shrink the DGV and as the rows with data expand increase the Height of the DGV But the scroll bars make it easy to just add a few blank row's”_ … ? … I am lost as to how/why the “scroll bars” would make adding empty rows any “easier.” … ? … Also, you state that… _”I have never had good results using bound data to the DataGridView.”_ … ? … What does “good results” mean here? I would think that using a data source either worked or did not work.

Comment: In short… I can only say that using a properly implemented data source to the grid is going to make many things much-much easier for YOU. As I previously commented, NOT using a data source only pushes MORE work onto YOUR plate unnecessarily. I am confident your efforts would be better spent trying to figure out “why” the data source does not work as you expect.

Comment: @JohnG I might agree to binding the SQLite DB to the DGV Not sure I know how but will explore. As for styling the DGV with code I will update my question with the code I use I just find it simple to implement and use in other projects. I found a less than elegant fix for the sorting issue just omit the code that does the sorting I can see the new date in the LastVisit column so while it is not sorted I know I have visited the site

Comment: @JohnG Where did your DataAdapter answer go ? ? Please RE post I was trying to convert it to VB.Net

Comment: I had one last question… is the main goal here to “fill” the grid of the “dead” space to the right and bottom of the grids size? If it is, then there are easier ways to accomplish this. Getting the columns to fill the dead space on the right is not difficult and the grid has features for this. Rows on the other hand are a different story, but doable. Can you verify if this is a goal as I can supply additional code to get rid of the empty space on the right and bottom of the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as getting the data from the SQLite DB into the grid… you almost have it in the `ViewSearches` method. The command text looks good; however you are using an `SQLiteDataReader`. This is resorting to reading the data line by line.

I suggest you use the `SQLiteDataAdapter` instead. With it you can get the `DataTable` from the DB in one shot. First create and initialize a `DataSet`, then create a new `SQLiteDataAdapter` then add your command to the data adapter something like…

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (SQLiteDataAdapter sqlDA = new SQLiteDataAdapter()) {
  conn.Open();
  sqlDA.SelectCommand = cmd.CommanText;
  sqlDA.Fill(ds, “tableName”);
  if (ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
    //return ds.Tables[“tableName”];
    dgvLinks.DataSource = ds.Tables[“tableName”];
  }
}
```

This will add a `DataTable` to the `DataSet` `ds` called “tableName” if the query succeeded.

Then simply use that `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to the grid… something like…

```
dgvLinks.DataSource = ds.Tables[“tableName”];
```